# mouse movement lag in javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am moving an image of the bat according to the position of the mouse,i want to limit its boundary. when i include the if condition the webpage becomes laggy. any solutions?

```
 //my js code is below   
    onmousemove = function(e)
    {
        // console.log("mouse location:", e.clientX, e.clientY)

         if(e.clientY>200&&e.clientY<340&&e.clientX>90&&e.clientX<500)
        {
        batLeft=e.clientX;
        batTop=e.clientY
        $("#bat").css("left",e.clientX);
        $("#bat").css("top",e.clientY);
        $("#score").text(score);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Probably because the onmousemove event is fired to many times and making the calculation on every event. Maybe throttle or debounce can help you out. https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

Comment: @simeon irudhayaraj You might want to include some more code to help us better understand why.